# how can i know the IP where the data that comes from in php

Tags: php

i have a fingerprint project for register/login , i have several of them so i want to know from where i logged in (from which IP) i tried

```
<?php 
      if(($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == "192.168.0.106"){
           echo "1";}?></TD>
```

192.168.0.106 is the finger print IP since it is connected to my router via WIFI it return a blank space , I TRIED 127.0.0.1 INSTEAD OF 192.168.0.106 AND IT SHOWED ME THE STRING "1". does REMOTE_ADDR only show 127.0.0.1 only if so how can i see the 192.168.0.106 address? in another word how can i know the IP where the data that comes from ?
by the way iam using localhost ( XAMPP server)

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the correct way. If you're seeing 127.0.0.1 that just means you're probably connecting to `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` using your browser aswell. Logically, in such cases, the OS uses the loopback device.

Comment: Possible workaround would be connecting via `192.168.0.106` (I don't actually know if your OS uses the corresponding network adapter in such cases - but I would assume so)

Comment: You asked the same question an hour ago, what is different now, or didn't the duplicate answer your question (if not please add why so this won't be closed again).

Comment: that question was different from mine i am asking to show the ip not theip loop back ( ip that the data comes from )

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, make sure not to trust data sent from the client. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains the real IP address of the connecting party. That is the most reliable value you can find.

However, they can be behind a proxy server in which case the proxy may have set the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`, but this value is easily spoofed. For example, it can be set by someone without a proxy, or the IP can be an internal IP from the LAN behind the proxy.

This means that if you are going to save the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`, make sure you *also* save the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` value. E.g. by saving both values in different fields in your database.

If you are going to save the IP to a database as a string, make sure you have space for at least **45 characters**. [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) is here to stay and those addresses are larger than the older IPv4 addresses.

(Note that IPv6 usually uses 39 characters at most but there is also a special [IPv6 notation for IPv4 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) which in its full form can be up to 45 characters. So if you know what you are doing you can use 39 characters, but if you just want to set and forget it, use 45).

Comment: duplicate answer

Comment: might be helpful :)

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] gives me 127.0.0.1 and i want 192.168.0.106 instead and $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'],  does not show anything